# How to prove $\int_{-\pi}^\pi (f(x))^2dx\le \int_{-\pi}^\pi (f'(x))^2dx$

Tags: integration, inequality, integral-inequality

Let $f$ be $C^1$ in $[-\pi, \pi]$ and satisfies $\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)dx=0$, periodic boundary condition.

Then, prove that $\int_{-\pi}^\pi (f(x))^2dx\le \int_{-\pi}^\pi (f'(x))^2dx$.

I try to prove it by Parseval's equality(with $X_n=\sin nx$) and Schwartz inequality,

but then some constants come out. Also why condition $\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)dx=0$ needs?

Give some advice.

Comment: If the condition is dropped, then the claim is false (eg constant functions)

Answer (score 1):

This is known as Wirtinger's inequality. See the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger%27s_inequality_for_functions) for its proof.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function  ${f(x)-f'(x)}^2$ . Integrate this function from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ . As this is a positive function this definite integral is greater than or equal to zero . Now expand the ${f(x)-f'(x)}^2$ using $(a-b)^2$ .  In the question he meant that $f(x)$ is an odd function which means $f'(x)$ is an even function . The product $f(x).f'(x)$ is also an odd function and when you integrate, this the term becomes zero . Arrange the other two terms you will get the result . :)

Comment: I think $f$ might not be odd?

Comment: The condition ∫π−πf(x)dx=0  indicates that the function is an odd function .

Comment: There are functions that are not odd and satisfies that....

Comment: Can you please give an example which satisfy the condition , integration from -a to +a of a function is zero and the function is not odd

Comment: $\cos x$ on $[-\pi, \pi]$

Comment: I think I edited ${(f(x)-f'(x))}^2$ incorrectly as ${f(x)-f'(x)}^2$.