# If $f$ is $2 \pi$ periodic and $\int_{0}^{2 \pi} f(t) dt=0$ then $\int_{0}^{2 \pi} (f(t))^2 dt \le \int_{0}^{2 \pi} (f'(t))^2 dt$

Tags: inequality, fourier-analysis, definite-integrals, periodic-functions, integral-inequality

Given $f$ a real differentiable function, $2 \pi$ periodic such that $\int_{0}^{2 \pi} f(t) dt=0$ show that:

$\int_{0}^{2 \pi} (f(t))^2 dt \le \int_{0}^{2 \pi} (f'(t))^2 dt$. When does equality hold?

Comment: See [Wirtinger's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger's_inequality_for_functions).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772586/how-to-prove-int-pi-pi-fx2dx-le-int-pi-pi-fx2dx?rq=1

Comment: I didn't know the name, thanks!